# href issue in view-controler

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a page with a specific link that is to call a view. The view is displayed after the coresponding function in the controller is executed
The page html contains the following line

```
<a href="xxxxxxx">Click to view</a>
```

The controller contains

```
public function get_comments()
    {
        if(!file_exists('application/views/blog/list_comment_view.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }
        else
        {
            $row_nums=$this->blog->get_row_nums();
            $config['base_url']=base_url().'index.php/blog/list_comment_view';
            $config['total_rows']=$row_nums;            
            $config['per_page']=5;
            $config['num_links']=2;
            $config['full_tag_open']='<p>';
            $config['full_tag_close']='<p>';
            $config['first_link']='First';
            $config['last_link']='Last';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['comments']=$this->blog->get_comments($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
            $this->load->library('table');
            $this->table->set_heading('No','Title','Created','Modified','Action');
            $this->load->view('blog/list_comment_view', $data);
        }
    }
```

The list_view.php  is

```
<body>
<div>Welcome ,
<?php
    $array=$this->session->userdata('db_result');
    echo $array[0]['name'];
?></div>
<?php    

    $this->table->generate($comments);
    $this->pagination->create_links();
?>
</body>
```

I would like to know what I should replace XXXXXX with because I directly put "get_comments" in there but it fails to display the list_view.php. There is nothing shown since the value $comments in the list_view.php is zero sized.

**Sorry everyone, it works, actually, just fine. I forget to "echo" the generate($comments); :-D Thanks everyone for reading and for your concern too..**

Comment: I don't know codeigniter, but if I had to guess, it looks like you have to specify the per-page count on the url. So the `href` would be something like `/index.php/blog/list_comment_view/10`.

Comment: Do you want to execute the function "get_comments()" by clicking on that link you have mentioned above ?

Comment: I think Yes, I did that too because I thought I would also load the view for me. But nothing is shown at all.

Comment: I'm glad you've identified and solved your issue but, can I offer some advice? You are sort of breaking the MVC pattern by including assignments in your view and using variables like $array[0]['name']. Data should be handed to the view from the controller in a manner such that it requires a simple echo to display and that is it. In fact, if you enable php_short_tags in php.ini you should be able to write <?= $name;?> Furthermore, the comments generation should be looked after in the controller as well. It mite not seem like a big deal, but as your application starts to grow, it will matter.

Comment: One more thing, actually related to your question. The href you supply to <a> tags, ensure you either write `<?= site_url('controller/function');?>` OR ensure you identify a <base> HTML tag. That way, when you move your website to a live server, or change domains, you only have to make a single change and not x changes (where x is the total number of a tags in your application)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not loaded then load it in your controller (that is loading the view) by

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

If loaded (autoload), skip this line then

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("classname/get_comments");?>">Click to view</a>
```

classname is the name of your class that contains the function get_comments. For more information please read the documentation at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html