# Assist me in fixing the URL and created links please

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, url

```
<?php    

    $res=$comments->result_array();
    $i=1;
    $ar=array();
    foreach($res as $row){
        $a=array($i,$row['title'],$row['date_post'],
            $row['date_edit'],
            '<a href="edit_post?title='.$row['title'].'">Edit</a>',
            '<a href="delete_post?title='.$row['title'].'">Delete</a>');
        array_push($ar,$a);
        $i++;
    }    
    echo $this->table->generate($ar);
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();
?>
```

I have added two links (edit and delete) into my page and this post is preceded by this [href issue in view-controler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256054/href-issue-in-view-controler)

The previous post solution leads me to more confusion to handle the URL of each link created in the above source snippet such as `http://localhost/blog/get_comments/edit_post?title=something/` whereas I expect something like `http://localhost/blog/edit_post?title=something`. I am grateful for any help. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

The above source code works fine until I click on the Edit or Delete link as created in the above code, which is to parse the URL as `http://localhost/blog/get_comments/edit_post?title=something/`, whereas I expect something like `http://localhost/blog/edit_post?title=something`.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you reword it to be clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the URLs since they appear to be relative...

```
'<a href="edit_post?title='.$row['title'].'">Edit</a>',
'<a href="delete_post?title='.$row['title'].'">Delete</a>');
```

Should be:

```
'<a href="http://localhost/blog/edit_post?title='.$row['title'].'">Edit</a>',
'<a href="http://localhost/blog/delete_post?title='.$row['title'].'">Delete</a>');
```

If it only will appear in one place, then you might be able to get away with:

```
'<a href="../edit_post?title='.$row['title'].'">Edit</a>',
'<a href="../delete_post?title='.$row['title'].'">Delete</a>');
```